# iOS/Objective-C: Store Decimal as NSNumber in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsnumber

I have an attribute in CoreData used for sorting that is an NSNumber.  Currently, all of the values in it are NSNumbers represting integers, ie 1,2,3,4 etc.

However, I now have a reason to add some `NSManagedObjects` with intermediate values. Is it possible to store a decimal in an attribute in CoreData with a data type of NSNumber?

For example, I might have one managed object with a sort order of 1 and another with a sort order of 2.  I'd like to move one in between and give it a sort order of 1.5.

Is this allowed?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically Core Data supports many different types represented by `NSNumber`

- integer16 (short int)
- integer32 (int)
- integer64 (long)
- double
- float
- boolean

`decimal` is represented by `NSDecimalNumber`

You have to choose the appropriate attribute type in the Core Data model

Comment: So it is a wrapper on those.  OK.  Thx.